# There is no SYS schema in MySql working bench

Tags: mysql

I am a new MySql user and trying to get familiar with the MySql working bench. But there is no sys Schema and only have TEST Schema. And I am trying to install sys Schema but it said
Error installing sys Schema.
'>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'
Is there anybody who can help me?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

They are not shown by default, you have to request they are shown by doing

```
Edit -> Preferences -> SQL Editor
```

Then click the checkbox `Show metadata and Internal Schemas`